# How to format a date from a date object in the JSON file in SwiftUI?

Tags: json, swift, decoding

I'm getting the date from an API with a date object and format "yyyy-MM-dd". I want to change to something like "January 1, 2023".

The problem is, when I use the `.formatted()`, nothing shows up.

**PostData.swift**

```
struct CardInfo: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    let release_date: Date
}
```

**DetailView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    let release_date: Date

    Text(release_date.formatted())
```

**Error message**

`typeMismatch(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "release_date", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: You can decode a value to `Date` directly if it's a Double (the number of seconds since 2001/1/1). That's exactly what the error says. For any other format like a string you have to specify a [date decoding strategy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/datedecodingstrategy), in your case `.formatted` or `.custom`

Comment: It should be made clear that your issue is not with your SwiftUI code, it’s a problem decoding the JSON.